# How can I click over time slots from 9:00 am to 3:00 pm from Monday to Wednesday using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZemo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC1k5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC1k5.png)

**

> SunMonTueWedThuFriSat

**

Comment: Call the .click() method after finding the element. If you can't find it, attach the HTML code to your question and I will help you or use the xPath Finder. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph

Comment: <tr><th class="fc-axis fc-widget-header" style="width: 55px;"></th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sun" data-date="2023-02-19">Sun</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-mon" data-date="2023-02-20">Mon</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-tue" data-date="2023-02-21">Tue</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-wed" data-date="2023-02-22">Wed</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-thu" data-date="2023-02-23">Thu</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-fri" data-date="2023-02-24">Fri</th><th /

Comment: <tbody><tr data-time="00:00:00"><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 55px;"><span>12:00 am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"></td></tr><tr data-time="00:15:00"><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 55px;"><span>12:15 am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"></td></tr><tr data-time="00:30:00"><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 55px;"><span>12:30 am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"></td></tr><tr data-time="00:45:00"><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" s

Comment: @JuanMelnechuk Can u see the pictures attached with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must post your code, this is not a project request website.

However, this can help you:

```
start_time = "09:00"
end_time = "15:00"

# get the list of day elements
days = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fc-day-header")

# iterate over the days
for day in days:
    
    # only click on the days from Monday to Wednesday
    if day.text in ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"]:

        day.click()
        
        # iterate over the time slots
        timeslots = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fc-axis")
        for timeslot in timeslots:
            if timeslot.text >= start_time and timeslot.text <= end_time:
                # click on the timeslot
                timeslot.click()
```

Where `driver` is your WebDriver instance.